# Casting to (char) and assigning to (int) doesn't clear MSBs

Tags: c, casting, printf

In a previous answer of mine, I am casting an `struct` to a `char`, extracting a single byte of data, then explicitly casting the value to a `char`, then assigning to an int.

**Code Listing**

---

```
myStruct_t structToTest = { 16, 'A'};
myStruct_t referenceStruct;
memset(&referenceStruct, 0xFF, sizeof(myStruct_t));
int t1 = (char)(*(((char*)&structToTest)+i));
int t2 = (char)(*(((char*)&referenceStruct)+i));
printf("Byte #%02d - Test Struct:0x%02X - Reference Structs:0x%02X\n", i, t1, t2);
```

When I print this out, one of the two hex values prints as expected, but the other seems to be printing more than I want:

**Output**

---

```
Byte #00 - Test Struct:0x10 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #01 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #02 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #03 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #04 - Test Struct:0x41 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #05 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #06 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
Byte #07 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Struct:0xFFFFFFFF
```

If I explicitly perform a logical **AND** operation against the `0xFF` literal, I get the expected output:

**Code Listing**

---

```
int t1 = (char)(*(((char*)&structToTest)+i))    & 0xFF;
int t2 = (char)(*(((char*)&referenceStruct)+i)) & 0xFF;
```

**Output:**

---

```
Byte #00 - Test Struct:0x10 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #01 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #02 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #03 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #04 - Test Struct:0x41 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #05 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #06 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
Byte #07 - Test Struct:0x00 - Reference Structs:0xFF
```

Why is the masking operation I'm using necessary? Wouldn't the explicit cast truncate the data to 8-bits anyways?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but when you cast a *signed* char to a *signed* int, the *sign* bit is extended. (So use unsigned types if that's what you meant.)

Comment: @rici TIL, thank you. Is it more ideal to use `unsigned char` rather than `signed char` and applying a mask, like how I did, in the most general case? Also, your comment addressed my problem. If you put it into answer form, I will accept it formally. Thanks!

Comment: Explicit cast to `(char)` did limit the result to 8 bits.  It was the then assigning that result to `int` that caused a sign extension of the `char`'s sign bit.  Instead doing a cast and `& 0xFF` cause the 8-bit result of the cast to be anded with an _unsigned_ resulting in a _unsigned_ value.  That _unsigned_ value does not sign extend into the `int`.

Comment: The signedness of `char` is implementation-defined. `signed char`, `unsigned char`, and `char` are three distinct types; `char` has the same characteristics as one of the other two. You probably want `unsigned char`.

Comment: Never use `char` for anything else than characters. Use `signed char` or `unsigned char` instead.

Comment: By using `unsigned char` you'll also avoid other pitfalls with signed types like overflow and left shifts being undefined behavior.  With a modern enough compiler and high enough optimization levels, you'll encounter some real (nasty) bugs caused by the optimizer being too smart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but when you cast a *signed* `char` to a *signed* `int`, the sign bit is extended. So use unsigned types if that's what you meant.

It's generally better to use `unsigned` types than to mask, since it clearly expresses your intent. It might also produce more efficient code, although it's likely that the compiler will optimize away the unnecessary sign-extend and mask operation.

Since your data is, I assume, not actually characters but rather short binary codes, you probably should be using `uint8_t`.